# Suitescript - get values from multiple searchs and update record - passing parameters

Tags: parameter-passing, netsuite, suitescript, saved-searches

i have a custom record that has been created called a Consignment Tracker.   This is created when an item is received. The name is a combination of item name and serial number.   I want to pull item fulfillment and update with the consignment tracker.  I know the searches are right, I am just new to "functions" and parameters - hoping someone could tell me if I am passing the parameters correctly.  (and executing correctly)

```
`/**
 * 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType ScheduledScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record', 'N/search'],

function(record, search) {


        /*This function runs a search of all fulfillments that have a consigned item 
        **@returns {string} The id of a new license record
        /*
     
     
function getfulfillinfo(){

    var itemfulfillmentSearchObj = search.create({
   type: "itemfulfillment",
   filters:
   [
      ["type","anyof","ItemShip"], 
      "AND", 
      ["mainline","is","F"], 
      "AND", 
      ["item.type","anyof","InvtPart"], 
      "AND", 
      ["item.custitemmedium","noneof","94","95"], 
      "AND", 
      ["account","anyof","236","239"], 
      "AND", 
      ["createdfrom.type","anyof","SalesOrd"], 
      "AND", 
      ["itemnumber.custitemnumbereditionconsigned","is","T"], 
      "AND", 
      ["trandate","within","03/13/2023"]
   ],
   columns:
   [
      "line",
      "item",
      "serialnumbers",
      search.createColumn({
         name: "formulatext",
         formula: "CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR({item.name},INSTR({item.name},':')+2),'-'),{serialnumbers})"
      }),
      search.createColumn({
         name: "custitemnumbereditionconsigned",
         join: "itemNumber"
      })
   ]
        });

        var fulfillinfo = [];

        var searchResult = itemfulfillmentSearchObj.run().getRange({
              start: 0,
              end: 10
            });

        searchResult.forEach(function(result) {

        obj = {}

        obj.Name = result.getValue('formulatext');
        obj.Fulfill = result.id;
        obj.Fline = result.getValue('line');
        fulfillinfo.push(obj)
        return true
        };

        return fulfillinfo;


};

        /*This function runs a search of custom record consignment tracker  
        **@param {array} fulfillinfo - the values from the fulfillment search
        **@returns {string} The id of an existing consignment tracker
        /*
        
function getCTid(fulfillinfo){
    var customrecordconsignmenttrackerSearchObj = search.create({
       type: "customrecordconsignmenttracker",
       filters:
       [ - 
          ["isinactive","is","F"]
       ],
       columns:
       [
          "internalid"
       ]
    });

    var CTFilter = search.createFilter({       
            name:'name',
            operator: 'contains',
            values: CTName
        });
        customrecordconsignmenttrackerSearchObj.filters.push(CTFilter);

    var CTResult = customrecordconsignmenttrackerSearchObj.run().getRange(0,1);
    
    log.debug('CTResult', CTResult);
    
    CTResult.forEach(function(newresult) {
            
                var CTid = newresult.getValue('internalid');
                
       });
       
       return CTid;
    
    };

        /*This function updates the fulfillment record with the consignment tracker 
        **@param {array} fulfillinfo - the values from the fulfillment search, {sring} - CTid the id of the Consignment tracker
        /*

function updateFulfill(fulfillinfo,CTid) {
        
        /* {N/record.Record} */
        
    var CTFulfill = record.load({
    type: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT, 
    id: Fulfill,
    isDynamic: true
    });

      
    CTFulfill.selectLine({‌
        sublistId: 'item',
        line: CTindex
    });
  
    log.debug('index',CTindex);
      
    CTFulfill.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'custcoltranconsignmenttracker',
        line: Fline,
        value: CTindex,
        ignoreFieldChange: true,
        forceSyncSourcing: true

    });

    CTFulfill.commitLine({‌
        sublistId: 'item'
    });


    return CTFulfill.save ({
        enableSourcing: true
    });
    };
    

/**
     * Definition of the Scheduled script trigger point.
     *
     * @param {Object} scriptContext
     * @param {string} scriptContext.type - The context in which the script is executed. 
     *          It is one of the values from the scriptContext.InvocationType enum.
     * @Since 2015.2
     */
     
function execute(scriptContext) {

var fulfillsearch = getfulfillinfo();


var Fulfill = '';
var Fline = '';
var CTindex = '';

for (var i = 0; i < resultObj.length; i++) {
            
        
        Fulfill = resultObj[i].id;
        Fline = resultobj[i].getValue('line');
        CTindex = CTinfo[0].id;
        
        var CTinfo = getCTid();

var finish = updateFulfill(Fulfill, Fline, CTindex);
     
     
 };
 
 return {execute: execute};
    
    
});
`
```

Comment: you have at several syntax errors in your script. So the script wont' work anyway. E.g. in here: `filters:
       [ - ` — the minus sign is an error. Also IIRC it's filter, not filterS, so this is also an error. And so on

Comment: Sorry I should have added - I know there are some syntax errors..   I am mostly trying to work through the parameters...